# Jquery dynamic element function

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

There is a div id name is results. Here when I drag and drop marker is created a link a element. Also I write lat, lng value of link a element dynamically.  This is created first link a element. Later when I drag and drop marker will be created a second link element and it has new lat lng value. Then if I click any link a function doesnt work. I get an error is moveMarker is not defined.

```
   <div id="results" style="width:115px; height:40px; background-color:#46b8da;"></div>
    <script>
    $("#results").append('<a onclick="moveMarker('+lat+','+lng+')">'+lat+" "+lng+'</a>');
        $("#results a").on('click', '#results a', function moveMarker(lat,lng) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); 
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
        });     

    </script>
```

Comment: post your full code..

Comment: full code is 1200 lines.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the name `moveMarker` in the function expression like that, the scope of the name is only the body of the function. If you need to be able to call the function from outside, you need to define it outside.

```
function moveMarker(lat,lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); 
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}

$("#results").append('<a onclick="moveMarker('+lat+','+lng+')">'+lat+" "+lng+'</a>');
```

You don't need the `$("#results").on("click")` code because you already have the `onclick` attribute that does it.

You could instead remove the `onclick` attribute and do it with event delegation.

```
$("#results").append('<a class="move">'+lat+" "+lng+'</a>');
$("#result").on("click", "a.move", function() {
    var latlong = $(this).text().split(' ');
    moveMarker(latlong[0], latlong[1]);
});
```

Comment: It didnt work i get same error movemarker is not defined

Comment: Is the definition of `moveMarker` in the global scope? `onclick` functions have to be global.

Comment: $("#results").append will be inner $("#result").on ?

Comment: No, they're separate.